# Bearings Cooked?

Tags: freewheel, bearings

I have a Trek mountain bike. It is not new by any means.

The back  wheel should not freewheel, correct?

I am having the back wheel spin freely and I question the bearings.

Comment: In which direction does the wheel spin?

Comment: The bearings are there to allow the wheel to rotate easily. If rotation is stiff (and the brakes aren't on!) then the bearings may be the cause. The wheel should spin freely in one direction (the direction that moves the top of the wheel towards the front of the bike) and make the pedals spin with it when it spins the other way. Could you describe more precisely what the problem is? (Please use the "edit" link to include the information in the question).

Comment: I didnt think that the back wheel moved unless peddles are used this one freewheels\

Comment: @Chuck Please use the edit button to add a video of your problem.

Comment: @chuck if the rear wheel didn't freewheel when not pedaling then you wouldn't be able to coast.

Comment: Your description of the problem is not very clear and understandable.

Answer (score 4):

The rear wheel should spin freely, either impelled by the crank and chain or free-wheeling (crank and chain not moving). The fact that the wheel spins freely indicates that the bearings are *not* worn.